# CoordinatorLayout Behavior optimizations

Tags: android, optimization, android-coordinatorlayout, coordinator-layout

I would like to know if its worth to cache `getDimensionPixelSize` results in custom `Behavior`?

Comment: If the answer isn't, "It depends," like nearly every other performance question, I'm going to be disappointed.